# Cannot import BinaryPayloadBuilder from pymodbus

Tags: python, modbus-tcp, pymodbus

I tried to write this code below:

```
from pymodbus.payload import BinaryPayloadBuilder
```

But raises an error:

```
ImportError: cannot import name 'BinaryPayloadBuilder' from 'pymodbus.payload'
```

Need your help please.

Comment: What is your `pymodbus` version? if you are a Linux user try it to get PyModbus version: `pip show pymodbus`